# Merging rasters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I've been trying to merge some raster tiles at work and I've been getting an error message saying I don't have the correct permissions. This works fine on my home pc.

Any obvious reasons for this?

QGIS at work runs on an application virtualisation client. Also 3rd party repos won't work. Set proxy settings to allow standard QGIS repo and that works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you have read and especially write permissions to the destination folder for the data (any temporary folders if required)?

Comment: You could try making a virtual raster (*.vrt) from the images. If this loaded properly you could then save it as a local GeoTIFF. N.

Comment: Yep I've got permissions to all the folders and tried to save to my memory stick, same problem. I've tried to make a virtual raster too with the same issue. I think the easiest option would be just to merge it at home and take it in on a stick. It's just a bit frustrating though!